# How to place the constraints for a view at the middle inside the tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, xcode8

I have the following screenshot for placing the view inside the UITableViewCell:

[image: The screenshot]

Currently i am using the following constriants:

A) Leading to the container view.
B) Trailing to the container view.
C) Top to the container view.
D) Bottom to the container view.

But in larger sizes the constraints are not satisfying like this:

[image: In 6s iPhone Screen]

How to correctly place the constraints if i am putting the wrong constraints?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not centered is because your constraint uses a fixed value. So your view is X points from the left side. It will still be fixed to the left if the screen size changes.

To center the view, add these two constraints:

- Center Vertically in container
- Center Horizontally in container